# MYSQL v8 Privileges

Tags: mysql, sql-grant

MySQL v8
command line and with phpmyadmin

I am logged into mysql as root (FULL Privileges) and I am trying to assign ALL privileges on a specific database to a user.
It gives them all privileges but DOES NOT allow Administration GRANT on the database (See Attached)[image: Snapshot]

This is the same result for direct command line or phpmyadmin

Any ideas please?

Thanks in advance
P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ... WITH GRANT OPTION`.

That means you grant all the privileges to the target user, as well as the privilege to grant those privileges to others.

Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html:

> The optional WITH clause is used to enable a user to grant privileges
> to other users. The WITH GRANT OPTION clause gives the user the
> ability to give to other users any privileges the user has at the
> specified privilege level.
>
> To grant the GRANT OPTION privilege to an account without otherwise
> changing its privileges, do this:
>
> ```
> GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'someuser'@'somehost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
> ```

Comment: Hi Bill I have used the following cmd. Is this not correct      GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON  database_name.* TO 'thisuser'@'%';

Comment: Add `WITH GRANT OPTION` as the last clause, between `'%'` and `;`.